# Can Youtube play nicely with Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm developing a Rails4 app which will be able to embed and play back videos hosted on Youtube in my application's pages. I need to hook into some of the video player's events, so I'm creating the Youtube object via an API call:

```
<script id="video_script" ></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var scriptTag = $("script#video_script");
  scriptTag.parent()[0].insertBefore(tag, scriptTag[0]);

  var youtube_player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    youtube_player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: <%= @video.id %>,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    ....
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
     ....
  }    
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly well when the page is first loaded, but doesn't work when a user navigates between pages with turbolinks enabled, since the document ready event doesn't fire, and consequently the Youtube code doesn't know to issue the callback to `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`.

So, I was wondering if there are any workaround that would get the Youtube API to call the API Ready method for the `page:change` event to make it work with turbolinks, in addition to the `document.ready` event? I've tried digging through the api script that gets downloaded from Youtube, but couldn't find anything in there that would solve the issue, and I'm also a little hesitant to be running a local version of Youtube's script.

Comment: Anyone? Has no one come across a way to embed Youtube videos in turbolinks-enabled pages so far?

Answer (score 3):

Turbolinks reload only content of title and body (so watch out for polluting head with too many scripts). To avoid it I check if YT object exists. Plus I do additional call to onYouTubeIframeAPIReady on turbolinks 'page:load' event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* load youtube js api */
var reloadYoutube = function () {
   /* if YT already initialized return */
   if (window.YT) { return; };
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
};
reloadYoutube();
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady && onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
});

/* youtube callback */
var ytplayer = null;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    // it is important to return when window.ytplayer 
    // is already created - because you will be missing
    // certain methods like getCurrentTime
    if (!window.YT || window.ytplayer) {
        return;
    }
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('main_player_div', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: getVideoId(),
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery-turbolinks gem, https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks . Then just make sure to wrap your code in $( document ).ready() .